# GStreamer extract JPEG image from MJPEG UDP stream

Tags: udp, jpeg, gstreamer, mjpeg

I am using the following command to try to take a single JPEG picture from a MJPEG over UDP stream with GStreamer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=53247 ! jpegdec ! jpegenc ! filesink location=test.jpeg
```

The problem is even if I manage to get a snapshot of the stream as JPEG image, the pipeline doesn't stop and the size of the output image keep growing until I manually stop the pipeline.

I also tried the option `num-buffers=1` but I only get a completely black Image then.

Is there a command that would allow me to take a JPEG format snapshot from the stream properly?

Comment: what about decoding and then encoding with jpegenc ?

Comment: With num-buffers=1 you only get one udp package, thus cannot get a full image. Try with *imagefreeze*, it will mage the stream freeze after one image (not sure if this is OK for you). If you want a proper solution, write a GStreamer app (use same pipeline as above, but stop stream after one buffer has pass filesink pad.

Comment: @otopolsky Thanks for your answer, I tried to replace `jpegparse` by `jpegdec ! jpegenc`. It gave me the same result as my first command but since `jpegparse` is in the Gstreamer bad plug-ins I think that using the `jpegdec` and `jpegenc` modules is more appropriate.

Comment: what happens when you set num-buffers=1 and add -e to the gst-launch ?

Comment: I get an unreadable jpeg image, probably because of what @matildagl described. If I only use `-e` or `imagefreeze` the pipeline doesn´t stop until I hit CTRL+C

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that partially reply to my question.

I empirically set the variable `num-buffers` to 75, which enough in my case to get a full image and give me JPEG files with a reasonable weight.

The command is the following:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc port=53247 num-buffers=75 ! jpegdec ! jpegenc ! filesink location=test.jpeg`

But since `num-buffers` is set empirically, I think this solution is not the most adapted.